# Nominatim search: Why not combine structured requests with q?

Tags: api, openstreetmap, nominatim

the API states `DO NOT COMBINE WITH q=<query> PARAMETER` in the section about structured queries at [the nominatim Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim).

Can you provide any reason for that? Since there is no parameter for every possible field, it seems like I can not really avoid combining them.

There is, for example, `district` for most geolocations (at least in germany).

Answer (score 0):

Because, as the documentation states, these parameters are still *experimental*. For why combining them is a bad idea at the moment you have to look at the [source code](https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim). Note that Nominatim is under constant development and consequently this situation will likely improve in the future.

Comment: 'look at the source code' is not really an answer in my opinion

Comment: That's true. But as far as I know there are only 2 people in the world who are able to answer you that question more precisely. And chances for reaching them here are pretty low. Try http://help.openstreetmap.org instead.